# Connecting to Canon PIXMA iP4000R over the network

Tags: networking, windows-vista, printer, canon-pixma

I have a Canon PIXMA IP4000R printer, with a normal network connector.

I've connected it to the network, and verified with my router that it has an IP address, and responds to pinging while connected and on, and not when unconnected and/or off, so I know I got the right IP address.

Unfortunately, it's a printer I've had a while and I can't find the manual nor the cd that came with it, so any instructions on how to get it set up so that I can print to it over the network I don't have.

I'm hoping someone here can help me with some pointers as to what to set up.

I have Windows Vista x64, and I tried the "Add printer" and selected the network option, it did not find any available printers I could add.

Then I tried first hooking it up over USB, so that it was installed and added to Windows, then I tried adding another port to it, but unfortunately it can't be autodetected what kind of port/driver would suffice, so I'm a bit stumped there as well.

Anyone can give me a hand with this?

---

**Edit**: Ok, I found that by pointing my web browser to the IP address of the printer, I got up a web page where I can enable and disable various interfaces, including a wireless network (WIFI) interface, who knew. Unfortunately, it doesn't tell me anything related to how I would configure Windows to actually talk to it.

---

**Edit #2**: When I try adding the printer manually, after inputting the IP address, it sits there trying to recognize the TCP/IP port, and then ends up on a dialog that asks me to pick either a standard port (dropdown), or a custom port (dialog). The dropdown lists a lot of choices, unfortunately I don't know which one to pick (and I suspect I'll have to try all the Canon types at some point), and the custom dialog asks me for port number, and 9100 doesn't work.

If I pick the Generic network card (default type in the combo), then it asks me to pick the make and model of printer. After doing that, and getting it to display in the printer list, going to the property pages and asking for printer status just tells me the printer is not responding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Vista I usually do this:

Printers -> Add Printer -> Add Local Printer -> Create New Port (Standard TCP/IP) -> Autodetect, Enter the Printer IP Address, port fills out automatically.

After this, it asks for drivers which you should already have from hooking by USB.

Comment: After talking to the printer (I assume), it starts "Recognizing TCP/IP port...", sits there for a while, and ends up asking me which port type the printer is on. I'll augment the question.

Comment: Ok, the printer status still doesn't work but printing works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get the port number step last time I did this, though it was HP.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac I needed to have my firewall allow incoming connections for the automatic detection to work.

The drivers that came on the cd may be old anyhow; more recent versions can surely be found on the net. For the archives, this is what I've written down after **installation on a Mac using OS X 10.5 Leopard**, a long time ago:

- The Canon PIXMA iP4000R drivers are included in a default installation of Mac OS X Leopard.
- The Network Setup program on the Canon printer cd does not work with Leopard. (My printer cd is labeled PIXMA iP4000R Setup Software & User's Guide, MCD 1.1, QH7-1581, copyright 2004.)
- The firewall must be set to allow incoming connections for "Canon IJ Printer Utility". (At least during installation: if not allowed, then the list for "Canon IJ Network" in the Network Setup program will be empty. And maybe this is also required for normal use, like to see the supply levels -- but I don't see those on demand anyway, though the printer does warn me when ink or paper runs out.)
- Given the notes I wrote down about the cd not being usable, I might have downloaded some new software then. **But maybe all that is needed is already included** and all that's to be done is go to System Preferences, Print & Fax to add a new printer. Here, go to More Printers, wait until "Searching for installed printer drivers" completes and select Canon IJ Network, which should then detect your printer. (*Can anyone confirm that no cd, nor downloads, nor setup program are required for Mac OS X Leopard?*)

For **OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard** things are a bit different. An early installation (while new drivers were not yet available) simply removed the existing iP4000R printer. When connecting it through USB it showed and installed without any question, but no luck for the network settings. On September 1st 2009 Canon released new CUPS drivers. On September 3rd Mac OS X Software Update did not know about this (yet?), and neither did the European website. However, Canon's USA and New Zealand sites list 10.6 drivers for the iP4000R. Other printers may have been updated as well. (But: meanwhile Apple Software Update might know all drivers too.)

So, for the iP4000R one can get CUPS driver version 10.26.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.5/10.6). (Meanwhile Apple Software Update has provided even more recent drivers, but even though I installed that update, I still seem to be using 10.26.0.0) Install it, and then use System Preferences to add a new printer as usual. Select the "Default" pane and just wait a few seconds (and ensure the firewall allows access) to see the iP4000R show automatically:

[image: Snow Leopard settings]

(In earlier drivers one would get a new "More printers" option in addition to "Default", "Fax", "IP" and "Windows". Not so for the 10.6 drivers.)

The type reads "canonijnetwork" and it gets a funny URL like `canonijnetwork://Canon/iP4000R?00.00.85.xx.xx.xx` (the last part being the MAC-address), even though my DHCP settings do not give the printer the name "Canon". My firewall now allows incoming connections for "Canon IJ Printer Utility" and "canonijnetwork.bundle". The Supply Levels are also shown on demand.

More info may be found at macosxhints.com, [10.6: Install Canon printer drivers in Snow Leopard](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090825110938102).

For a clean installation of **OS X 10.7 Lion**, using a printer that had already been configured: System Preferences, Print & Scan, click "+" for Add Printer, wait until the printer appears (exactly the same screen as in 10.6), select and accept the defaults (like Print Using: Canon iP4000R), button Add. This downloads additional printer software, which when clicking the Options button shows as Driver Version 10.51.2.0. I did not download anything myself, but had no firewall running (yet). Printing the test page was very quick (in a first try I thought nothing happened, so I clicked again, to find two copies).

For **OS X 10.9 Mavericks**, Jens commented:

> Canon recently released a new version of their IJ Network Tool (v. 4.4.1). Using this I was able to setup the network interfaces of my old ip4000r on OS X 10.9.5 without much problem. [Link to EU support site](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/PIXMA_iP4000R.aspx?type=download).

(I no longer own this printer; feel free to edit in other resources.)

Comment: Worth a shot, but doesn't seem to help. It asks for the name and ip address of the printer, then sits there trying to recognize the port, and ends up at the dialog that asks me to pick the right port type. I don't think I need the cd either, but I'm pretty sure there was some instructions in the package on how to set up the network part.

Comment: Surely the manuals are easy to find: http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&tabact=SupportDetailTabAct&fcategoryid=257&modelid=10438#DownloadDetailAct

Comment: Yeah, and they mention something like a "BJ Network Tool", which unfortunately isn't part of the downloadable files, at least that I can see.

Comment: I have never understood what's in the drivers, and what's in the setup program. Running the setup program on a Mac, using that Network Tool was part of the setup sequence, so it may have been installed on the fly. In daily usage I can also open it from the printer queue, or run it as a standalone program (on a Mac, in `/Library/Printers/Canon/BJPrinter/Utilities/`). But it seems those utilities are also present on a Mac on which I never installed the printer, which may indicate it has come with the drivers...

Comment: Canon recently released a new version of their IJ Network Tool (v. 4.4.1). Using this I was able to setup the network interfaces of my old ip4000r on OS X 10.9.5 without much problem. Link to EU support site: http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/PIXMA_iP4000R.aspx?type=download

Answer (score 1):

Procedure which should work on a Windows 7 x64 install, at least it did for me:

- Download Driver Addon from Canon, this link works
  http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0100002264/01/aomwin110ea24us.exe
- Install the Driver Addon, and go to Control Panel, Add Printer
- Select Local Printer, choose to Create a New Port. Make sure to select "Canon BJNP Port"
- Now the Canon Addon should appear, where you can enter IP, MAC, or just Auto Detect, just make sure it finds your printer
- After adding port, change from "Add new port" to "Use Existing Port", here the new Canon BJNP port should be visible
- In the next screen, you need to update the Windows Printer driver list, press "Windows Update"
- The Windows Update might take a while, but eventually you should be able to select Canon, and find your "Canon Inkjet PIXMA iP4000R" in this list
- Select and install Printer, and you're done!

Note: Sometimes the Port may change, or the IP of the Printer. Then it can be nice to have an opportunity to update the current port. Use "Canon IJ Network Tool" for this, available here: http ://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0900003906/02/ip5200r_ip4000rndwin255_ntwin255en.exe

Also, you might want to reconfigure you're printer. Then you may use the http client mentioned above, but there is also a "PIXMA Wireless Setup Assistant" available for this, youæll find it here: http ://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/1/0200000651/04/CanonAPChkTool_win210en.exe

Hope this is of some help!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tool](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0036224.asp?model=) on the Canon web-site and it works:

> With this software, you can install, view or configure the network
>   settings of the printer that is connected through a network.